# Why is there a "le" before "requiert" here?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, traduction, expressions, histoire

I read this short story and I saw this sentence:

> La poitrine découverte, Tristan le requiert encore de l'épée et le frappe  sur les flancs d'un coup si violent que l'air en retentit.

I translated it as

> The chest exposed, Tristan needed it again/still(?) of the sword and struck it on the side so violently that the air rang.

I know that "frapper d'un coup" is an idiom for "strike" so no problem with that, but I really got confused with this "Tristan le requiert encore de l'épée" why there's a "le" and a "de l'"

Context:

> Le dragon avait deux cornes au front, les oreilles longues et velues,les yeux étincelants à fleur de tête tels des charbons ardents, le mufle haut dressé comme celui d’une guivre, la langue hors de la gueule, crachant de toutes parts le feu et le venin, le corps écailleux,des griffes de lion et la queue d’un serpent. Le monstre a vu Tristan : il rugit et enfle tout son corps. Le preux rassemble ses forces et, se couvrant de son écu, broche son destrier avec une telle vigueur que le coursier,tout hérissé de peu, bondit pourtant contre la bête.
>   La lance de Tristan heurte les écailles et vole en éclats. Aussitôt le preux tire son épée,la brandit et en assène un coup terrible sur la tête du dragon, mais sans même entamer le cuir. Le monstre a senti l’atteinte : il lance ses griffes contre l’écu, les y enfonce et en fait voler les attaches. La poitrine découverte, Tristan le requiert encore de l’épée et le frappe sur les flancs d’un coup si violent que l’air en retentit. Vainement : il ne peut l’entamer.
>   Alors,le dragon vomit par les naseaux un double jet de flammes : le haubert de Tristan noircit comme charbon,son cheval s’abat et meurt.Mais aussitôt relevé,Tristan enfonce la pointe de son épée dans la gueule du monstre :elle y pénètre toute et lui transperce le cœur. Le dragon pousse une dernière fois son cri horrible et meurt.
>   Quand Tristan le vit mort, il lui coupa la langue jusqu’à la racine, car il voulait la conserver comme un trophée de victoire, et il la dissimula dans sa chausse,entre la chair et l’étoffe.

Comment: C'est grammaticalement correct, mais ça ne veut pas dire grand chose, sans le contexte. "le" se réfère à quelque chose ou quelqu'un décrit précédemment. "de l'" complémente le verbe requérir (peut avoir plusieurs sens: avec, de la part, ...)

Comment: "Tristan le requiert et le frappe" is the simplified form, where both "le" have the same usage and refer the same person. "de l' " is used as "requérir de l'épée", which, I guess, may "challenge to a duel", but not sure, I've never heard this...

Comment: Je vais ajouter un peu de contexte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This text is a translation of a Middle Age version of *Tristan et Iseult* written originally in Norman language in the 12th century by [Béroul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9roul). So you must expect to encounter lots of vocabulary issues even if it is supposed to be a translation into "modern French".  The problem with this translation is that although it is supposed to be in modern French the translator has used words that have changed meanings nowadays. It must be very confusing for someone who does not master the language sufficiently. This translation is usually used in French secondary schools for native French students.

**requérir de l'épée**
Here the verb *requiert* is used in the sense it had in the Middle Ages. In a warfare context *requerre* meant "to choose your adversary in order to attack him". So the sentence just means that Tristan **attacked** the dragon (*le*) once more **with** his sword.

From the *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*

> *Requerre* s'employait en ancien français pour « prier (qqn), demander (qqch.) » [v. 980], réclamer (qqch.) » [v. 1050] et, spécialement dans un contexte guerrier « choisir (son adversaire) pour l'attaquer » et « attaquer » (1080), emplois disparus.